# String comparison - two characters look identical but have different ASCII values?

Tags: javascript, html, string, string-comparison

I have two strings, one in an HTML file and one in a JS file that look identical in my IED (VSCODE) and also any text editor.

I can search for the value and find both strings as there is a difference in what is the space between two of the works, I've looked these up with an ASCII value tool and the difference is the following:

string 1 uses 32 20 40 (DEX, HEX, OCT)
string 2 uses 160 A0 240 (DEX, HEX, OCT)

What is this and how do I bring the HTML and JS in alignment?

Comment: HEX 20 = Space,  A0 = No Break space.

Answer (score 3):

If you look up the characters associated with those ASCII codes (a good resource is https://ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm), you'll find these values:

- **String 1 (Dec 32, Hex 20):** Space
- **String 2 (Dec 160, Hex A0):**  [Non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space)

These would look exactly the same as each other in a text editor because they are non-printing characters. A non-breaking space acts just like a space except that it prevents an automatic line break at its position when text is wrapped.

If you want these values to be identical you'll have to either change the first value to a non-breaking space character or change the second value to a regular space character.

More on special characters: https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/specialchars.html